# Check if data exists in anolther table and if not then insert

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, insert

I have 2 database, 1 database is called new and another database is called test.
The database (new) continuously accepts new data from a processor while the database (test) has no data at all. Now I want to insert data from database(new) to database (test) every second but will not transfer if a data coming from database (new) exists already in database(test). The transferring every second is done but my query is not working correctly.

**Here's my query**

```
INSERT INTO [test].[dbo].[test]
SELECT TOP 1 * 
FROM [NEW].[dbo].[new] cr
WHERE
NOT EXISTS (SELECT TOP 1 * FROM [test].[dbo].[test] c
          WHERE cr.smsdt = c.smsdt)
```

when i try running my query this is the error i got

```
An explicit value for the identity column in table 'test.dbo.test' can only be specified when a column list is used and IDENTITY_INSERT is ON.
```

I tried using this

```
SET IDENTITY_INSERT [test].[dbo].[test] ON
```

but still the error stands.

Thank you in advance for all the help.

Answer (score 2):

As the error says you need to mention `column list` in insert when you are using `IDENTITY_INSERT ON`

```
INSERT INTO [test].[dbo].[test](colum1,colum..)
SELECT TOP 1 colum1,colum2,..
FROM [NEW].[dbo].[new] cr
WHERE
NOT EXISTS (SELECT  * FROM [test].[dbo].[test] c
          WHERE cr.smsdt = c.smsdt)
```

There is no use in `Top 1` while using `Not exists` in `subquery` and also you are checking data exists in same table not in another table.

Comment: @ColourDalnet - Yeah :D